# QLPreviewController issue in Xamarin iOS 8

Tags: ios8, xamarin.ios, xamarin, qlpreviewcontroller

I am having an issue with QLPreviewcontroller presentation in iOS 8. When it is pushed, the UINavigationBar gets transparent and the UI of the app gets disturbed (though it is working fine on iOS 7), I am developing in Xamarin.

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0))
{
     DocPreviewViewController docPreivewVC = new DocPreviewViewController (this.Title, downloadedTime, fullFilePath); //DocPreviewViewController is subclass of UIViewController

     this.NavigationController.PushViewController (docPreivewVC, true);
}
```

Here is the Output in iOS 8:
[image: QLPreviewController when pushed in iOS 8]

**And** if I try to **Present** it by wrapping into a UINavigationContorller , the document gets hide under the QLPreviewControllers toolbar and user has to tap the screen to hide the navigation bar and see the upper portion of document. Is there a way to hide this tool and show only my own UINavigationBar? Is this a known behaviour that the QLPreviewController’s navigation bar always overlaps the document and user has to tap it to reveal the full document? 
 Here is the code that I have tried:

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) 
{
        DocPreviewViewController docPreivewVC = new DocPreviewViewController (this.Title, downloadedTime, fullFilePath);
        UINavigationController nav = new UINavigationController (docPreivewVC);
        nav.HidesBarsOnTap = false;
        nav.HidesBarsOnSwipe = false;
        this.PresentViewController (nav, true, null);
}
```

iOS 8: Screen shot when used

[image: QLPreviewController when presented]

Kindly give me suggestion how can I achieve the appearance of document as of iOS 7 i.e: Hiding the top toolbar of QLPreviewController and showing only NavigationController's navigation bar like this:

[image: iOS 7 Screenshot]

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a bug in iOS 8. You should probably file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: You should really use `UIViewController.PresentViewController()` instead of pushing the preview controller on the stack directly. Maybe this already solves your issues.

Comment: @Krumelur: Seems like he has already tried the PresentViewController but it had it's own effects!

Comment: @JamalZafar Well, he wrapped it into a `UINavigationController` and then presented it instead of presenting it directly.